# How to upload file in Webform content type

Tags: 7, webforms, files

I want to be able to upload a file with [Webform](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform), is their any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can upload files to webform. Create field for resume by choosing type as file. Check following screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks  .. Its working ,I have another problem that when i write something on body part of webform , then field name(i.e. Body ) comes on screen ..how to remove it?

Comment: Hi, is there any way to upload a file as an attachement to the webform from admin so that when the user submits the form to download that attached file?